# How can I change the parameters of a default constructor?

Tags: c++, class, constructor, static, c++17

I have a class called `Date` that controls the date.

I have a constructor `Date()`. If this constructor is uninitialized, a default date will be put in its place by a private, static data member called `default_`.

I have initialized `default_` in `Date.cpp` as follows:

```cpp
Date Date::default_{1, Month::January, 1900};
```

Where the first argument is an `int` for the day, second is an `enum class` called `Month` for the month, and third is an `int` for the year.

When I run this program, I can print the date and it shows the correct default date that has been set by `default_`.

### Question:

I want to be able to change the default date with a function:

```cpp
setDefaultDate(int day, Month month, int year)
```

How can I do this? I have tried to implement `setDefaultDate()` as follows but it is not working:

```cpp
void Date::setDefaultDate(int day, Month month, int year)
{
    default_ = {day,month,year};
}
```

### Code:

Date.h:

```cpp
#ifndef DATE_H
#define DATE_H
// date.h
// class Date declaration

#include <cassert>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

enum class Month
{
   January = 1,
   February,
   March,
   April,
   May,
   June,
   July,
   August,
   September,
   October,
   November,
   December
};

class Date
{
public:
   // return the day of the month
   int   day () const;
   // return the month of the year
   Month month () const;
   // return the year
   int year () const;

Date();
   static void setDefaultDate(int day, Month month, int year);

private:

   int   day_;
   Month month_;
   int   year_;

   static Date default_;
};

// standalone function for printing the date
void printDate(const Date& date);

#endif
```

Date.cpp:

```cpp
// date.cpp
// Implementation of the Date class

#include "date.h"

int Date::day() const
{
   return day_;
}

Month Date::month() const
{
   return month_;
}

int Date::year() const
{
   return year_;
}

// Note, this standalone function is not part of the Date class
void printDate(const Date& date)
{
   cout << date.day() << "/"
       // cast to an integer to allow the month to be sent to the stream
<< static_cast<int>(date.month()) << "/"
       << date.year()
       << endl;
}

Date Date::default_{1, Month::January, 1900};

void Date::setDefaultDate(int day, Month month, int year)
{
   default_ = {day,month,year};
}

Date::Date()
{
   day_ = default_.day();
   month_ = default_.month();
   year_ = default_.year();
}
```

### Example

```cpp
int main()
{
    auto date_1 = Date{};
    date_1.setDefaultDate(29, Month::September, 2020);

    printDate(date_1);
}
```

Expected output:
29/9/2020

Actual Output:
1/1/1900

It compiles, but the `setDefaultDate()` function is not working, and the default date is being outputted that was declared in `default_`.

Comment: _"it is not working:"_ is no problem description. Please add some more details. Also your title is a bit misleading, since a default constructor doesn't take any parameters you could change.

Comment: You don't have 3-arguments constructor (add `Date::Date(int day, Month month, int year)`)

Comment: *"If this constructor is uninitialized, a default date will be put in its place by a private, static data member called 'default_'"* Why? Just initialize the members in the constructor. There's no need for this `default_` variable.

Comment: The code you say compiles [does not compile](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/cra359) for me because of the missing constructor for the default date's initialization. `setDefaultDate` doesn't even enter the picture yet.

Comment: @cigien: There is if the default date needs to be changed at runtime. Now granted, this is a horrible idea, but if that's what he's going with, then that's how it has to happen.

Comment: @fas I wanted a constructor without any arguments and then have an option to change the default date set up by 'default_'. I just do not know how to implement the setDefaultDate(int day, Month month, int year) function

Comment: @churill It compiles, however, when i try to use the setDefaultDate function, the date does not change and it is the same one that was initialized using default_

Comment: @NicolBolas Yes Exactly. I am not saying it is a good idea however, This is what I want to try do. If anyone can help, please try

Comment: @John No...it doesn't when you add `default_ = {day,month,year};`. But anyway, you know how to write a constructor, right? You know how to write functions that take three parameters. Then you should get a constructor with 3 parameters working :) So what's stopping you? Did you think about the easy way, just setting `default_.day = day;` and so on?

Comment: @churill Yes I of course know all that stuff but that isn't the point. I am trying to do it a certain way, I apologize that it is not the most efficient way of doing things. Yes, I have tried setting default_.day = day; and so on but it did not work

Comment: @John Then please clarify _what_ does not work. The best would be a [mre] that reproduces _exactly_ the error you are stuck on right now.

Comment: @churill Ok, I added to the question

Comment: @John The probably better, easier and more flexible idea is to define a copy constructor, derive one or more classes from `Date` which only implement getter functions, and various default values you want to be usable in your application (e,g, `LinuxDefaultDate`, `WindowsDefaultDate`, etc.). These ones can be passed to your `Date(const Date&) otherDate) ` copy constructor as necessary. No hassle with `setDefaultDate()` or such.

Comment: @John It ... doesn't compile. Please make sure the code you post actually compiles as you have posted it. But anyway, you should walk through your `main` line by line and think about what values `date_1` will have after each line. Maybe use a debugger for this. Note that `setDefaultDate` changes the static variable _only_. There is no reason to expect any changes in `date_1`. Might as well make an answer from all of this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's step through your `main` line by line:

```
auto date_1 = Date{};
```

What will this do? It will call `Date::Date`, which will read all of the values from `default_` into `date_1`. At this point `default_` is `1/1/1900` and `date_1` now is the same. Then

```
date_1.setDefaultDate(29, Month::September, 2020);
```

will change `default_` and `default_` only. I'm not sure why you expect `date_1` to change here, maybe because you've called it like a non-static member function? You probably meant to change the default date *before* reading from it. You can do it like so:

```
int main()
{
    // call it like static function
    Date::setDefaultDate(29, Month::September, 2020);

    // Only then read from it.
    auto date_1 = Date{};
    
    // prints 29/9/2020
    printDate(date_1); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `setDefaultDate()` method sets *only* the value of `default_`, which `main()` has already made a copy of when calling the `Date()` constructor for the `date_1` object.  Changing the value of `default_` afterwards has no effect whatsoever on the value of `date_1`.  When you print `date_1`, you output the value it was initialized with.  Changing the value of `default_` will only have an effect on *subsequent* `Date` objects that you create afterwards.

If you want to change the value of `date_1`, you need to either:

1. call `setDefaultDate()` *before* calling `Date()`:

```cpp
int main()
{
    Date::setDefaultDate(29, Month::September, 2020);
    Date date_1;
    printDate(date_1); // 29/9/2020
}
```

2. add non-static methods to mutate the values of a `Date` object.  You should also add a non-default constructor that can take a user-specified date as input, eg:

```cpp
class Date
{
public:
   Date();
   Date(int initialDay, Month initialMonth, int initialYear);

   ...

   void setDay (int newValue);
   void setMonth (Month newValue);
   void setYear (int newValue);

   ...
};
```

```cpp
Date::Date() :
   Date(default_.day_, default_.month_, default_.year_)
{
}

Date::Date(int initialDay, Month initialMonth, int initialYear) :
   day_(initialDay),
   month_(initialMonth),
   year_(initialYear)
{
}

void Date::setDay (int newValue)
{
   day_ = newValue;
}

void Date::setMonth (Month newValue)
{
   month_ = newValue;
}

void Date::setYear (int newValue)
{
   year_ = newValue;
}

...
```

```cpp
int main()
{
    Date date_1;
    printDate(date_1); // 1/1/1900

    date_1.setDay(29);
    date_1.setMonth(Month::September);
    date_1.setYear(2020);
    printDate(date_1); // 29/9/2020

    date_1 = Date(9, Month::September, 2020);
    printDate(date_1); // 9/9/2020

    Date date_2(31, Month::December, 2020);
    printDate(date_2); // 31/12/2020

    Date::setDefaultDate(1, Month::April, 2020);

    Date date_3;
    printDate(date_3); // 1/4/2020
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**I will show you a modified version of your code that should do what you need to, if I understood it correctly. I changed your code a bit, in order to use a single file**

java is not C++, C++ is not java. And `static` things in C++ goes not the java way. Maybe you are used to that.

One thing is in C++ you can set up the defaults running code just *outside* of `main()` and outside the class as

```
...
}; // class Date{}

int Date::default_day = 1;
int Date::default_month = 1;
int Date::default_year = 1900;

void printDate(const Date& date);
void setDefaultDate(int, int, int);

int main(void)
{
...
```

And so you have the first set of defaults loaded.

> And if you do it inside `main()` it compiles but the linker will
> complain about all 3 of them as unresolved.

- for `setDefaultDate()` you can just declare it as Date's `friend`

```
    friend void setDefaultDate(int, int, int);
```

- a convenient and common alternative to `PrintDate()` is to declare another `friend` to `Date`, as

```
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream&, Date&);
```

#### An example using your code

**Program shows**

```
just a date at start (should use defaults 1900,1,1)

printDate()
 d: 1 m: 1 y: 1900

Now sets default to 1901/3/2

printDate()
 d: 2 m: 3 y: 1901

Now declared new Date instance as d3(2019,8,7)

printDate()
 d: 7 m: 8 y: 2019

Now print all 3 dates using "<<" operator, redefined for Date class

printDate using insertion operator '<<'
        year is 1900 month is 1 year is 1900

printDate using insertion operator '<<'
        year is 1901 month is 3 year is 1901

printDate using insertion operator '<<'
        year is 2019 month is 8 year is 2019
```

#### `main()` is

```
int main(void)
{
    cout << "\njust a date at start (should use defaults 1900,1,1)\n";
    Date d1;
    printDate(d1);
    cout << "\nNow sets default to 1901/3/2\n";
    setDefaultDate(2, 3, 1901);
    Date d2;
    printDate(d2);
    cout << "\nNow declared new Date instance as d3(2019,8,7)\n";
    Date d3(2019, 8, 7);
    printDate(d3);
    cout << "\nNow print all 3 dates using \"<<\" operator, redefined for Date class\n";
    cout << d1 << d2;
    cout << d3;
    return 0;
}
```

- Code uses `printDate()` and also the overloaded `<<` as an alternative to `printDate()`. I left two `cout` for the 3 `Date` just to show that you can chain the printing as with any other `cout` call.
- The program sets the defaults *before* and *inside* `main()`
- I added a 2nd constructor that accepts `day`, `month` and `year` as arguments

#### the complete example

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Date
{
private:
    int  year_;
    int  month_;
    int  day_;

public:
    int year()  const { return year_;  };
    int month() const { return month_; };
    int day()   const { return day_;   };

    // default as Date d;
    Date() : 
        year_(default_year), month_(default_month), day_(default_day) {};
    // as Date d(2020,9,8)
    Date(int y, int m, int d) :
        year_(y), month_(m), day_(d){};

    friend void setDefaultDate(int, int, int);
    friend ostream& operator<<(ostream&, Date&);

private:
    static int  default_year;
    static int  default_month;
    static int  default_day;

}; // class Date{}

int Date::default_day = 1;
int Date::default_month = 1;
int Date::default_year = 1900;

void printDate(const Date& date);
void setDefaultDate(int, int, int);

int main(void)
{
    cout << "\njust a date at start (should use defaults 1900,1,1)\n";
    Date d1;
    printDate(d1);
    cout << "\nNow sets default to 1901/3/2\n";
    setDefaultDate(2, 3, 1901);
    Date d2;
    printDate(d2);
    cout << "\nNow declared new Date instance as d3(2019,8,7)\n";
    Date d3(2019, 8, 7);
    printDate(d3);
    cout << "\nNow print all 3 dates using \"<<\" operator, redefined for Date class\n";
    cout << d1 << d2;
    cout << d3;
    return 0;
}


void printDate(const Date& date)
{
    cout << "\nprintDate()\n" <<
        " d: " << date.day() <<
        " m: " << date.month() <<
        " y: " << date.year()
        << endl;
};

void setDefaultDate(int day, int month, int year)
{
    Date::default_day = day;
    Date::default_month = month;
    Date::default_year = year;
};

ostream& operator<<(ostream& out, Date& date)
{
    cout << "\nprintDate using insertion operator '<<'\n" <<
        "\tyear is " << date.year_ <<
        " month is " << date.month_ <<
        " year is " << date.year_ <<
        endl;
    return out;
};
```

No religion here. I compiled it just under **MSVC 19.27**